# How to create a function to run an undefined amount of coordinates through a function to format them in JS

Tags: javascript, iteration

I'm trying to create a function run an undefined amount of coordinates through a function that normalizes them, and then format them with the second function. This is the first function, to normalize the coordinates (Working for it's purpose):

```
function normalizeCoord(value) {
  let noBrackets = value.replace(/[\[\]]+/g, "").replace(/ +/g, "");
  let splitValue = noBrackets.split(",");
  let lat1 = splitValue[0];
  let long1 = splitValue[1];
  let lat2 = splitValue[1];
  let long2 = splitValue[0];
  let result1 = `(${lat1}, ${long1})`;
  let result2 = `(${lat2}, ${long2})`;

  if (result1.charAt(0) === "-" || result2.charAt(0) === "-") {
    result = result2;
  } else {
    result = result1;
  }

  let latInt1 = parseInt(lat1, 10);
  let latInt2 = parseInt(lat2, 10);
  let longInt1 = parseInt(long1, 10);
  let longInt2 = parseInt(long2, 10);

  if (latInt1 < -90 || latInt1 > 90 || latInt2 < -90 || latInt2 > 90) {
    throw new Error("Invalid latitude");
  }

  if (longInt1 < -180 || longInt2 > 180 || longInt2 < -180 || longInt2 > 180) {
    throw new Error("Invalid latitude");
  }

  return result;
```

This is the function that I want to use to run the undetermined amount of coordinates through (not working):

```
function formatCoords(...values) {
  let coords = values;

  for (var i = 0, n = coords.length; i < n; i++) {
    normalizeCoord(coords);
  }

  return coords;
}

console.log(
  formatCoords(
    normalizeCoord(("42.9755,-77.4369", "[-62.1234, 42.9755]", "300,-9000"))
  )
);
```

I'm honestly not sure on how I'm meant to go about this. I tried the above, expecting to maybe get somewhere (not the intended result of course, but of normalized coordinates that I could then format) but I only get back the first set of normalized coordinates (-77.4369, 42.9755), then the throw error of "Uncaught Error: Invalid latitude at normalizeCoord"

Comment: `("42.9755,-77.4369", "[-62.1234, 42.9755]", "300,-9000")` is the same thing as `"300,-9000"` due to the [comma operator (`,`)](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator). Did you mean `[ "42.9755,-77.4369", "[-62.1234, 42.9755]", "300,-9000" ]`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to consume the return value from `normalizeCoord`. Right now you do the normalization and then just throw away the result.

Also, pass just the single coords at a time:

```js
for (var i = 0, n = coords.length; i < n; i++) {
    try {
        const normalized = normalizeCoord(coords[i]);
        coords[i] = normalized;
    } catch (error) {
        // Error, do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This has solved my main issue here, but opened up a new one - in the instance of an error being thrown, I'd like to ignore the variable that caused the error/not return it. I am thinking that the try/catch method would be best here but I'm not sure how I would do that.

Comment: `try/catch` works, I updated my example to show how

Answer (score 1):

you need to use a [try.. catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

```js
function normalizeCoord( strVals ) 
  {
  const rgxfns = /[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?/g; // extract floats values
  let
    [v1,v2]   = strVals.match(rgxfns).map(Number) 
  , [lat,lon] = (v1 < 0 || v2 < 0) ? [v2,v1] : [v1,v2]  // .?
    ;
  if (lat < -90  || lat > 90  )  throw new Error('Invalid latitude');
  if (lon < -180 || lon > 180 )  throw new Error('Invalid longitude');
 
  return `(${lat}, ${lon})`;
  }

function formatCoords(...values)
  {
  const coords = []
    ;
  values.forEach( val => 
    {
    try 
      {
      let coord = normalizeCoord( val );
      coords.push({in:val, out: coord })
      }
    catch (err) 
      {
      coords.push({in:val, out: err.message })  
      }
    })
  return coords;
  }

console.log(
  formatCoords( '42.9755,-77.4369', '[-62.1234, 42.9755]', '300,-9000' )
  );
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
.as-console-row::after {display: none !important;}
```